# Python save captcha image from url? Error 401

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a problem to save captcha as png.
Here is my code so far

```
import requests
url_login = "https://www.hackthis.co.uk/?login"
r_login = requests.post(url_login, {'username': 'darkcyber', 'password': 'secr3tp4s5'})
print r_login.status_code
if "Invalid login details" in r_login.text:
        print "Failed to login"
else:
        print "Login success"
url_captcha = "https://www.hackthis.co.uk/levels/extras/captcha1.php"
r_captcha = requests.get(url_captcha)
#print r_captcha.status_code << 401 instead 200
#whats next?
```

Comment: You need send cookies in second request (GET). Because first login returns session cookies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need download image and save to local as new file.

Here's the sample code:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://url.com/captcha.php')

f = open('yourcaptcha.png', 'wb')
f.write(r.content)
f.close()
```

**UPDATE after your comments:**

```
import requests
url_login = "https://www.hackthis.co.uk/?login"

r_login = requests.post(url_login, {'username': 'darkcyber', 'password': 'secr3tp4s5'})

if "Invalid login details" in r_login.text:
        print "Failed to login"
else:
        print "Login success"

url_captcha = "https://www.hackthis.co.uk/levels/extras/captcha1.php"
r_captcha = requests.get(url_captcha, cookies=r_login.history[0].cookies)

print r_captcha.status_code

f = open('yourcaptcha.png', 'wb')
f.write(r_captcha.content)
f.close()
```

Comment: I get 401 response code instead 200, anyway I have already authenticated. Whats wrong?

Comment: @DarkCyber can you put here the original URL?

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: @DarkCyber updated answer.

Comment: It works :D, anyway can you tell me about `cookies=r_login.history[0].cookies` more clear, I dont see in documentation. confuse with history[0]

Comment: @DarkCyber, after success login it redirected to main page. That's why I get the cookies of POST request result before redirect (status_code=302). That's why I used history.